# How to automatically populate a sheet on Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I understand the use of the vlookup (on a basic level). I am trying to figure out if it is at all possible to fill one sheet with data (for example: Name, date, order, invoice number, items) and then have a second sheet serve as the invoice using that information. I am hoping that the first sheet I can input several orders in every row. The hold up is I hope to not have to create a new sheet for every invoice.

I plan on using this spreadsheet for tracking orders, and I would like to then take that order information and have an invoice be filled automatically with that information (without having to fill out the invoice for every order) I can't think of a good place to start with this one...

Comment: populated a sheet with what? please format your question properly instead of writing a single passage

Comment: Sorry, I tried to clarify. Basically, I just need a solution to have an invoiced automatically filled with information already put in a separate excel sheet.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want all the fields in the invoice sheet to be captured in another sheet. For every invoice, you require one line entry.

Answer (score 1):

This can be very easily done using the copy paste special feature

[How to link to values in another worksheet](http://www.exceldigest.com/myblog/2008/04/05/how-to-link-to-values-in-another-worksheet-workbook/)

> If you want data from one worksheet to be linked to, or shown in
>   another worksheet then follow these steps:
>
> 1. In the sheet you want to link to (source) select the cell where the value is.
> 2. Right click and select Copy.
> 3. In your main sheet (target), select the cell where the value is to be displayed.
> 4. Right click and select Paste Special.
> 5. When the dialog box appear click on the Paste Link button.
> 6. The value in the source sheet will now be reflected in the target sheet.
> 7. Every time the source sheet is updated, the target sheet will also be updated with the new values.
> 8. The same procedure can be applied to link to data in another workbook.

Answer (score 1):

If every row of data is one invoice, you can set up an Invoice sheet with a cell for invoice number, then use VLookup or Index/Match to look up the other fields of that invoice and place the values in different cells.

Example: say Sheet1 column A contains the invoice numbers, column B contains the customer name for the invoice number listed in column A. Create an Invoice sheet. In cell B2 enter the Invoice number. To show the customer name in cell B4, enter this formula in cell B4:

```
=Vlookup(Invoice!B2,Sheet1!$A$1:$Z$100,2,false)
```

In words: Look at the table in sheet1 from A1 to Z100. In column A, find the number that is in B2 of the invoice sheet, then return the value from the second column of the table (which will be column B).

This will work with the Invoice number in the leftmost column. If you need to look up data to the left of the Invoice number, the approach will be different.

I don't want to confuse you with too many scenarios. Try this one out and report back.